# Pair combinations of elements in dictionary without repetition

Tags: python, combinatorics, python-itertools

In python, I have a dictionary like this...

```
pleio = {'firstLine': {'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 
                      'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 
                      'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 
                      'enf4': ['12', 'free']}

        'secondLine':{'enf5': ['56','bgb']
                      'enf6': ['67','kiol']
                      'enf7': ['11','dewd']
                      'enf8': ['464','cona']}}
```

I would like to make paired combinations with no repetition of the elements in the inner dictionary, to end up with a result like this...

```
{'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf2': ['48', 'free']}
{'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf1': ['54', 'set']}
{'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}
{'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf1': ['54', 'set']}
{'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}
{'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}
```

I built a function which lets me do it...

```
import itertools

def pairwise():
    '''
    '''
    leti=[]
    for snp, enfs in pleio.items():        
        for x in itertools.combinations(enfs, 2 ):
            leti.append(x)    
    pleopairs=[]
    for i in leti:
        pipi={}
        for c in i:
            pipi[c]= enfs[c]
        pleopairs.append(pipi)
```

..but i was wondering if there's a more efficient way, like another specific function from itertools, or any other source. By the way, I found a function called "pairwise" in the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) documentation. But I don't know how to adapt it, if would be possible in my case, or improve my attempt. Any help?

Comment: `enfs` is going to be the last value from `pleio` processed. It is almost certainly not what you wanted to use. It is not clear what you do want to do in the second half of your function.

Comment: Does `pleio` have more than one key?

Comment: Yes, pleio has several hundreds of keys... I just wrote one, for sake of simplicity. 
In the second part of the function, I just iterate the dictionary gathering the values for each of the elements in the tuple pairs and building dictionaries of two elements, and appending them to a list.

Comment: Then you will get incorrect results, and the step is not necessary.

Comment: But it actually works... Why incorrect?

Comment: You take elements from the last value processed in the `for snp, enfs in pleio.items()` loop. The `enfs` local variable is still set by the time you come to the `for i in leti` loop later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `combinations` approach was correct, you just need to turn the results of each combination into a dict again:

```
import itertools

def pairwise(input):
    for values in input.itervalues():
        for pair in itertools.combinations(values.iteritems(), 2):
            yield dict(pair)
```

This version is a generator, yielding pairs efficiently, nothing is held in memory any longer than absolutely necessary. If you need a list, just call `list()` on the generator:

```
list(pairwise(pleio))
```

Output:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(list(pairwise(pleio)))
[{'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf3': ['34', 'set']},
 {'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf3': ['34', 'set']},
 {'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']},
 {'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf2': ['48', 'free']},
 {'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']},
 {'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}]
```

You can even combine the whole thing into a one-liner generator:

```
from itertools import combinations

for paired in (dict(p) for v in pleio.itervalues() for p in combinations(v.iteritems(), 2)):
    print paired
```

Which outputs:

```
>>> for paired in (dict(p) for v in pleio.itervalues() for p in combinations(v.iteritems(), 2)):
...     print paired
... 
{'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf2': ['48', 'free']}
{'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf1': ['54', 'set']}
{'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}
{'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf1': ['54', 'set']}
{'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}
{'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}
```

If you are on Python 3, replace `.itervalues()` and `.iteritems()` by `.values()` and `.items()` respectively.

Comment: I tried with a dictionary of length > 1 and realised about my error... I was on my way to correct it, but this solution is absolutely amazing. 
Anyway, I wonder why itertools has not a straightforward pairwise generator for this. Thanks again!

Comment: @peixe: This is a straightforward pairwise generator. You just had to turn the output back to the format you wanted (you input key-value tuples, not dictionaries, so the output is tuples, not dictionaries).

Comment: yeah, i meant "a straightforward generator" like this one.

Comment: @peixe: All we do is take your specific nested input format and massage it to the desired output format. The library generates the pairs for you according to your desired rule: combinations without repetitions. There isn't anything more the library can do without becoming too specific to be generally useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all pair combinations, you could probably use the following which is shorter, but I would not say this is more efficient.

```
[dict([(x,vx),(y,vy)]) for (x,vx) in pleio['firstLine'].iteritems()
                       for (y,vy) in pleio['firstLine'].iteritems()
                       if x < y]
```

Output

```
[{'enf3': ['34', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']},
 {'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf3': ['34', 'set']},
 {'enf2': ['48', 'free'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']},
 {'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf3': ['34', 'set']},
 {'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf2': ['48', 'free']},
 {'enf1': ['54', 'set'], 'enf4': ['12', 'free']}]
```