# Pairwise Combinations from Python dictionary data

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations

I have a spreadsheet of data in different catagories that I read in from a csv and into a  dictionary, with the column as the key.

I want to make pairwise combinations out of the data but can only seem to make combinations out of keys.

For example if my data  is

```
{"x":['1','2','3'],
 "y":['4','5'],
 "z":['puddi']}
```

I've worked out using itertools and itervalues (and code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562613/pair-combinations-of-elements-in-dictionary-without-repetition)) that I can make the following:

```
[{"x":['1','2','3'],"y":['4','5'},
 {"x":['1','2','3'],"z":['puddi']},
 ...]
```

I know itervalues returns the values that I want to use to make my pairwise combinations, and that the itertools.product would yield the combinations I want but I'm struggling to bring it all together into the desired formatt of:

```
{"x":['1','2','3','1','2','3'...],
 "y":['4','5','4',....],
 "z":['puddi','puddi','....]}
```

Any help would be useful

Comment: Thanks so much for the solutions guys they're really helpful. 

But I've realised that I've made a mistake in my question; itertools.product will give me the exhaustive/cartessian combinations whereas I want the all pairs/pairwise combinations (The shape of my example  data yields the same amount of exhaustive/cartessian combos and the pairwise I got confused).

So what I've done now is used an OrderedDict, to sort the values and attempt to do a product with the first two rows then fill in the rest of the space with alternating values from the other rows

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that you know the keys for the dictionary beforehand, One way to do this would be -

```
from itertools import product
result = {'x':[],'y':[],'z':[]}
for a,b,c in product(data['x'],data['y'],data['z']):  #data is the original dictionary
    result['x'].append(a)
    result['y'].append(b)
    result['z'].append(c)
```

The above sends in the list (values from the dictionary) to `itertools.product` , and then each combination/product that `itertools.product` yields is added to the lists in the result dictionary.

Demo -

```
>>> data = {"x":['1','2','3'],
...  "y":['4','5'],
...  "z":['puddi']}
>>>
>>> from itertools import product
>>> result = {'x':[],'y':[],'z':[]}
>>> for a,b,c in product(data['x'],data['y'],data['z']):
...     result['x'].append(a)
...     result['y'].append(b)
...     result['z'].append(c)
...
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'x': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
 'y': ['4', '5', '4', '5', '4', '5'],
 'z': ['puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi']}
```

---

A generic solution -

```
keys = list(data.keys()) #Or the list of keys you want Ex. - keys = ['x','y']
result = {k:[] for k in keys}
import operator
for item in product(*operator.itemgetter(*keys)(data)):
    for i, k in enumerate(keys):
            result[k].append(item[i])
```

Demo -

```
>>> keys = list(data.keys())
>>> result = {k:[] for k in keys}
>>> import operator
>>> for item in product(*operator.itemgetter(*keys)(data)):
...     for i, k in enumerate(keys):
...             result[k].append(item[i])
...
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
{'x': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3'],
 'y': ['4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5'],
 'z': ['puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi']}
```

Comment: What exactly is *operater.itemgetter(*keys)(data) doing? In your static solution you've clearly got the 3 sets that your multiplying but what does this reference return?

Comment: operator.itemgetter(*keys)(data) returns a list of lists from data based on the keys in te `keys` list. The `*` operator at beginning and for `(*keys)` is for unpacking, not multiplying

Comment: Thanks for that
Also if I wanted just find the product of x and y, how do I specify a range of keys. I've tried changing *keys to *keys[0:1] but that does something weird and the keys only get one value

Comment: Changes the `keys = list()` to whatever keys you want in it as a list. Example - `keys = ['x','y']` .

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
d = {"x":['1','2','3'],
 "y":['4','5'],
 "z":['puddi']}
>>> {k: list(v) for k, v in zip(d.keys(), zip(*itertools.product(*d.values())))}
{'x': ['1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3'],
 'y': ['4', '4', '4', '5', '5', '5'],
 'z': ['puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi', 'puddi']}
```

As you said, `itertools.product` on the values creates the data you want, but it is transposed so that the data are in "rows" rather than "columns" (i.e., the first row is `"4", "1", "puddi`").  Using `zip(*...)` on this transposes it so you get one tuple for each column.  You can then zip this with the original keys to realign each column with its original key.

You cannot control the order of the rows in the product, because that depends on the order of the keys in the dictionary, which is arbitrary.  (However, as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), `dict` does guarantee that calling `values` and then `keys` produces aligned values, which is why it's safe to call them separately as I did above.)  If you need to control the order of the rows, you'll have to make use of some ordered structure in addition to or instead of your dict (for instance, a separate list of the keys as in Anand's answer below).