# Selecting parents in a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to make it so when I run my code that the parents from the array of parents are only used once. I have shortened the numbers just for troubleshooting. I want my program to select from my array one single possible combination. Once that single element is picked I want it to be unusable again.

The code I'm currently using:

```
#Importing the needed functions

import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
from itertools import permutations as permutation


#Defining my mating function where I want each parent in the parent array to be only once and not repeat. 
def mating (parents):
    parent1 = 0 
    parent2 = 0
    parent1 = permutation(parents,2)
    parent2 = permutation(parents , 2)
    print ("parent1: ", list(parent1))
    print ("parent2: ", list(parent2))

#Function used to create my 4 parents and 3 genes
def generateRandom(population , m):
   Population = np.random.rand (population,m)   
   return(Population)

# main code where I am setting returns from the functions to other vairables to call later
for i in range(2):
    candidateSolution = generateRandom(4,3)
    print ("the solutions: ", candidateSolution)
    full_population = mating(candidateSolution
```

The output I get now is a permutation where element 0 is used against element 1, 2 ,3.

What I would like it to do is have a random parent assigned to parent 1 and a random non-used parent to be parent 2. I'd like to use each parent only once.

A topic I was looking at that showed what I was getting was: [Pair combinations of elements in dictionary without repetition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562613/pair-combinations-of-elements-in-dictionary-without-repetition)

However, they wanted to have it where element 0 is being used multiple times. I want it to be used only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code used to fix this issue was:

```
for i in range (int(len(parents)/2)):
    parent1 = parents[i]
    parent2 = parents[-i-1]
    print ("Parent1: ", parent1)
    print ("parent2: ",parent2)
```

This works for the fact that my length was going to be a even number.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting unique random combinations in an ordered list, you may select defined items in an shuffled list. This way, you are sure of the unicity of the parents and guarantee the randomness for the breeding.

```
from random import shuffle
parents = [i for i in range(10)]
shuffle(parents)

n = len(parents)
couples = [(parents[i], parents[n-i-1]) for i in range(int(n/2))]

print(couples)
# an output obtained [(8, 7), (5, 2), (6, 9), (1, 0), (4, 3)]
```

Adapting to your routine, it turns into:

```
def mating(parents):
    n = len(parents)
    parents_1 = parents[:int(n/2)]
    # a small security if n is not even
    if n == 2*int(n/2):
        parents_2 = parents[int(n/2):]
    else:
        parents_2 = parents[int(n/2):-1]
    print("parent1: ", list(parents_1))
    print("parent2: ", list(parents_2))
    return parents_1, parents_2
```

Comment: With the GA I'm working on it has 100 people in the population and each person is made of 30 genes. This then means that I'd end up with repeats doing it your way wouldn't it?

Comment: Perhaps I did not understand clearly your question. But for sure, the code example above allows you to randomly build the pairs of parents without any repetition of parents. This is for the parents's selection. On  the other hand, you got me confused speaking of number of genes...

Comment: I'm putting your code into the code I have running right now. It took a second set of eye to make what you stated a bit clearer. Still working off bare basic python skills.

Comment: For the life of me I can't figure out how to use the code I posted to fit your shuffling mechanic.

Comment: Not that difficult: the parents '1' are the first half of the shuffled list, the parents '2' are the second half. I'll edit the code.

Comment: From a screenshot, I took while running my code. It show's that parent2 isn't considered. https://gyazo.com/6746ed6ef56b9e41c419628f891c0371 As you can see I did two iterations and it does parents1 as both parent1 and parent2 from the looks of it.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help on this. It is part of your code debugging and it is no longer a topic of the initial question.